# Why I cannot see array values on scala worksheet anymore?

Tags: arrays, scala, intellij-idea

I would kindly ask help for values of array. I am going to try explain with examples. When I write

```
var a = new Array[Int](10) or val a1 = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

I was able to see values of array.  Output was like below on scala worksheet before

```
a : Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

But recently I see only

```
a1: Array[Int] = [I@6b0910c9
```

How can I change, help me please.

[image]

Comment: You should consider editing your post.

Comment: Hello @Chobeat 
No I did not import anything and use [scala array](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Array.html). By the way for be sure I have created new project. I wrote same code and got same output as before. I would check more if you give any suggestion.

Comment: Scala and Java arrays are exactly the same thing.

Comment: I think I found a bug. [Related ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11103)